# Passing values from MySql to PHP. How to avoid NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, null, associative-array

I want to  dynamically populate a website menu, in PHP, by using MySql values.

MySql table is made up of two fields:
First one is called "category", the other one is called "parent".

But I would also need to specify some "subcategories", like:

**Categories**: MEN, WOMEN, BOYS, GIRLS 
**Subcategories**: SHIRTS, PANTS, SHOES, ACCESSORIES

So I thought to solve the problem by implementing a "parent" field in the table so that:

if parent=0 it means that it's a main category (MEN, WOMEN, BOYS, GIRLS)

if parent=1, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's MEN'S SHIRT
if parent=1, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's MEN'S PANTS
if parent=1, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's MEN'S SHOES
if parent=1, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's MEN'S SHIRT

if parent=2, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's WOMEN'S SHIRT
if parent=2, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's WOMEN'S PANTS
if parent=2, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's WOMEN'S SHOES
if parent=2, it means that it's a subcategory, therefore it's WOMEN'S SHIRT

...ETC...

(Maybe there's a more efficient way, but that's how I thought of it)

Now, if I set my PHP code like this:

```
$parent_arr_id = $parent_arr['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent ='parent_arr_id'";
$query_child = $db->query($sql);
while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_child)) :
echo $child['category'];
endwhile;
```

having parent=1 in my MySql DB, what should I get? 
 The correct output should be:
 
**Shirts, Pants, Shoes, Accessories**.

I instead get:
**Men,Women,Boys,Girls**

I triple checked the default values in the table, everything is correct, I can guarantee 100%. 
I manually made queries directely in MySql and it works.

So I carefully checked the first line, by echoing its variable like this:

```
$parent_arr_id = $parent_arr['id'];
var_dump($parent_arr_id);
```

But I get a **NULL** value! 
I think this is why I get 
**Men,Women,Boys,Girls** insted of 
**Shirts, Pants, Shoes, Accessories**. 
 Maybe they are the defaults values (?).

Checking online it seems that this is happening because it's an associative object array and it should be converted into a string array. I tried:

```
var_dump ($child['category']);
```

but nothig changes: **NULL**

Can anyone please help me? 
 I have no idea about how to solve such a dilemma! :) 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 1` ?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent ='parent_arr_id'";` First, if `$parent_arr_id` is a integer, remove the `'` as they are for strings only.. Secondly, you're missing the `$` in `$parent_arr_id` in your query... 3rd, this query is vulnerable to injection attack and instead I urge you to use [mysqli prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you @IsThisJavascript for your answer. I applied the correction you suggested. I get the following error: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given**

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I want to dynamically populate menu. I don't want statically pass values. Thanks.

Comment: Where is $parent_arr set? Have you tried a print_r on it?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have tried also print_r , same message: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given** $parent_arr is set above in the code. I hope you can see it clearly here: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0"; 
   $par = $db->query($sql); 
  
      while ($parent_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($par)) :
      print_r(array_values($parent_arr));
   endwhile;`

Comment: Of course you will get that error. Don't put code in comments, edit your question and put the code there. The point is to find out what the var contains before you get to the mysqi_fetch_assoc so you can find out why the sql is failing.

Comment: Put the print_r before your sql statement. Show the results by editing your question.

Comment: @SloanThrasher unfortunately I can't edit my question. I can't put my code there. I tred **print_r** on on my **$parent_arr** variable but I get **Men,Women,Boys,Girls** which is not what I want

Comment: if I **var_dump($genit_arr_id);** I get **NULL** in return.
If I **print_r(array_values($genit_arr));** I get **array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given**

Comment: If you're getting a boolean result from your query, that means it failed to execute. Verify that you have the table names correct. I advise you output the query to your browser, then run said query in your database. Are you using prepared statements or are you still using your previous method of querying? If it's the latter then `echo $sql;` after you have set it and execute query in the database.

Comment: I almost figured out how to solve the problem but  I lack knowledge to actually make it. The problem is this: When I perfom my query, result is passed to $child" array but...I only need to echo the "category" property within the array, and that's probably why I get **NULL** in return when I type `var_dump ($child['category'])`. In fact if I print the whole array I see it all. No problem at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Not able to solve the problem so far. I only want to say that I created a separated test.php file where there are not html tags in it. And it works! But when I replace my php code in my navigation.php (which includes html tags) it won't work: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in** . I rewrote the entire html tags manually including the bootstrap code. I really can't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was just becuse I was not putting the $ sign before variable name ($parent_arr_id). It should have been:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent =$parent_arr_id";